# Play: bower webjars not loaded into target folder

Tags: playframework-2.4, webjars

I have a play 2.4 subproject that uses sbt-sassify. It works fine, but I want to pull a bower dependency into the project so that my scss files can make use of it.  I followed the sbt-sassify instructions for this and added the following dependency to my build.sbt.

```
"org.webjars.bower" % "bootstrap-sass" % "3.3.6"
```

However, when I run the project, none of the scss from bootstrap-sass is in the target folder so that I'm able to import it into my scss.  If I use a dependency to a classic webjar such as

```
"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.6"
```

I will be able to see the bootstrap code in target/public/main/lib.

When I run the sbt-dist command, the bower jars will show up in my universal tar ball.

Is there anything else I need to configure?

Comment: I added that dependency to a Play 2.4 project then ran `activator assets` and the files were copied to `target/web/public/main/lib/bootstrap-sass` which I think is the right place.  Is that the case for you?

Answer (score 0):

`activator dist` will only package your project in several jars. The contents of all assets can be found in:

```
target/scala_<scala_version>/<prefix>-web-assets.jar/public/lib/bootstrap-sass
```

However, none of this makes sense when you're only trying to import the scss files into your own scss files. As of sbt-sassify version 1.4.0+ you can include web-jarred assets into your own files (without relying on the folder structure of your application).

I'm not sure which of the bootstrap files you're trying to import, but for instance if you'd want to the root of the bootstrap code you could use

```
@import "lib/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

P.S.

I'm the author of sbt-sassify and I've tested this with play 2.4.6 and sbt-sassify version 1.4.2. In case this does not solve things for you, can you create a repo on github exhibiting the faulty behaviour?